# Parsing a paragraph: detecting sentences without punctuation

Tags: python, text, nltk

Let's say I have the following text:

> Steps toward this goal include: Increasing efficiency of mobile networks, data centers, data transmission, and spectrum allocation Reducing the amount of data apps have to pull from networks through caching, compression, and futuristic technologies like peer-to-peer data transfer Making investments in accessibility profitable by educating people about the uses of data, creating business models that thrive when free data access is offered initially, and building out credit card infrastructure so carriers can move from pre-paid to post-paid models that facilitate investment If the plan works, mobile operators will gain more customers and invest more in accessibility; phone makers will see people wanting better devices; Internet providers will get to connect more people; and people will receive affordable Internet so they can join the knowledge economy and connect with the people they care about.

As you can tell by reading the text, these are multiple sentences (a list of points). How can I split this text into sentences? I've tried using python NLTK but no luck. Checking for uppercase letters won't work either, as it isn't very reliable.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you trying to parse the lists within the text (like "mobile networks, data centers, data transmission, and spectrum allocation") or just split the sentences? Is there a reason your data includes commas and semicolons, but not sentence ending punctuation?

Comment: @Blckknght I'm using NLTK to parse text taken from an article. This body of text exists in the article, but isn't correctly tokenized by NLTK because of its lack of punctuation. I'm trying to take this text and split it into sentences.

Comment: Might I suggest replacing the word "lists" with "sentences" (or "sentence boundaries") in the question title then? I'd started to post about the challenges of detecting an "A, B, or C" type list before reread your post and realized that might not be what you were after.

Comment: I am not sure I can perform this task by hand.  You are asking about a ridiculously difficult problem.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood you correctly this little code could help: (Note tested on python 2.7.5)

```
paragraph = 'Steps toward this goal include: Increasing efficiency of mobile networks, data centers, data transmission, and spectrum allocation Reducing the amount of data apps have to pull from networks through caching, compression, and futuristic technologies like peer-to-peer data transfer Making investments in accessibility profitable by educating people about the uses of data, creating business models that thrive when free data access is offered initially, and building out credit card infrastructure so carriers can move from pre-paid to post-paid models that facilitate investment If the plan works, mobile operators will gain more customers and invest more in accessibility; phone makers will see people wanting better devices; Internet providers will get to connect more people; and people will receive affordable Internet so they can join the knowledge economy and connect with the people they care about.'
words = []
separators = ['.',',',':',';']
oldValue = 0
for value in range(len(paragraph)):
    if paragraph[value] in separators:
        words.append(paragraph[oldValue:value+1])
        oldValue = value+2
for word in words:
    print word
```

**[EDIT]**
also you could add uppercase letter check easily with

```
if paragraph[value] == paragraph[value].upper():
    words.append(paragraph[oldValue:value+1])
    ...
```